# WPF Click event on dynamically generated column headers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gridview, mvvm

I have a ListView which contains a GridView. Its columns are dynamically generated with attached properties of the class "GridViewColumns" like this :

```
<GridView 
                ColumnHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderFilter}"
                self:GridViewColumns.DisplayMemberMember="DisplayMember"
                self:GridViewColumns.DisplayMemberFormatMember="DisplayMemberFormat"
                self:GridViewColumns.WidthMember="Width"
                self:GridViewColumns.HeaderTextMember="HeaderText"
                self:GridViewColumns.ImageTemplateMember="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}"
                self:GridViewColumns.ColumnsSource="{Binding WorkItemsColumns}"/>
```

Example of definition in GridViewColumns.cs :

```
[AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static string GetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextMemberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HeaderTextMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

The template of the gridview headers :

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderFilter" DataType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Button Name="FilterButton" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Height="18" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                        <Image Source="Wfl.Presentation.Tibco;component/Resources/Images/filter2.png" />
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Entete" Text="{Binding}"  FontSize="14"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

How can I define the Click event on the headers of that GridView ?

Comment: Do you want click even on the button or the header it self ?

Comment: You can use a eventtrigger for your datatemplate

Comment: Or just bind the Command of the button to a command in your ViewModel. That would be the easiest.

Comment: The button is for another function. The button is for filter and the click on the header for sort

Comment: <TextBlock x:Name="Entete" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="14">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>

Comment: Why dont you do it like that?

Comment: It will work on click on the TextBlock but I need that it works on all the area of the header